# Serverless | How to set Lambda authorizer to None (public API)

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway, serverless-framework

Please consider the following code (serverless.yml):

```
functions:
  exportCvToPdf:
    handler: handler.exportCvToPdf
    timeout: 20
    events:
      - http:
          path: export
          method: post
```

Deploying to AWS returns a link to the API endpoint.
CURL'ing the endpoint returns:

```
{"message":"Missing Authentication Token"}
```

**How can I make a public endpoint using Serverless Framework?**

I have tried the following:

```
functions:
  exportCvToPdf:
    handler: handler.exportCvToPdf
    timeout: 20
    events:
      - http:
          path: export
          method: post
          authorizer: none # None NONE "none" "NONE" "None" has also been tried
```

The above returns an error at deploy:

```
Function none doesn't exist in this Service
```

Comment: AWS often returns this error in cases not related to authorization at all. Please, make sure that you call a proper URL and the method of request is exactly POST. Also, remove the "authorizer" line from your serverless.yml

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should be able to just omit `authorizer` and your endpoint will be publicly accessible right after deployment. Ensure that you're calling proper URL with proper path and method. Could you share how are you calling the deployed endpoint?

Comment: Snap - I tried to GET a POST endpoint. Thanks for pointing me in the right direction!

Comment: Glad to hear you were able to resolve your issue!

Comment: had the same funny issue, thanks @Progress1ve